# as3: How to upload bitmap data to server using httpRequest

Tags: django, apache-flex, actionscript-3, forms

I captured screenshot of my ui element, and would like to send it to server, using httpService.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
var httpService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
httpService.method = "POST";
httpService.url = "/admin/compositions/add/";
httpService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onresult);
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(chessBoard.width,chessBoard.height);
var encoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
var data:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.img = data;             
httpService.send(obj);
```

But I don't see anything in files variable of request (django is the backend)
e.g.

POST dictionary

> QueryDict: {u'tournament': [u''],
>   u'img': [u'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n'],
>   u'sidetomove': [u'true'], u'idea':
>   [u'\u043c\u0430\u0442 \u043d\u0430
>   \u043f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435\u0434\u043d\u0435\u043c
>   \u0440\u044f\u0434\u0443'],
>   u'source': [u''], u'complexity':
>   [u'1'], u'opponents': [u'']}

Files dict:

> MultiValueDict: {}

Answer (score 1):

`u'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n'` is header of PNG file so it looks like encoding is not finished but this data is sent to backend.

To have file appear in `request.FILES` it have to be submitted with `multipart/form-data` content type (and properly encoded as multipart message).

Comment: maybe you can suggest why 
httpService.contentType = "multipart/form-data";

Gives:
MultiPartParserError: Invalid boundary in multipart: None

On server?

Comment: It's not only a matter of correct content type, also posted data must be properly encoded as multipart message. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages here you have example how this should look like. I hink there should be support for that in flex. Quick search resulted with http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html